# Where to find appID and masterkey when mongoDB is installed on AWS EC2 Machine. Parse Server

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-ec2, parse-server

I have mongoDB installed on AWS EC2 instance from where I am trying to connect Parse Server installed on my local pc. when I try to connect parse server to parse.com apps using their appid and masterkey it just works fine. but when I try to connect to my mongoDB instance on EC2 then it says "Server not reachable: unable to connect to server".
[image]

I already started the server using mongod command on the terminal.
I checked the securityGroup it is open to all requests.
I checked the database it exist with data in it.
I have the following code in configuration file to connect

```
   {
  "apps": [
    {
      "serverURL": "https://api.parse.com/1",
      "appId": "TWxCk7***************************JZ32k3",
      "masterKey": "S*********t3234*******************i",
      "appName": "ParseServer"
    },
    {
      "serverURL": "https://api.parse.com/1",
      "appId": "x544******************4343************SPtRO",
      "masterKey": "8B4******************Y32fkiiU782IL",
      "appName": "ParseServer 2"
    },
    {
      "serverURL": "http://dbuser:Password@ec2-**4-2**-**4-1*9.compute-1.amazonaws.com:27017/db",
      "appId": "x544******************4343************SPtRO",
      "masterKey": "8B4******************Y32fkiiU782IL",
      "appName": "AWS"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: ParseServer2 and AWS apps have same key because the db on EC2 is migrated from it.

Answer (score 1):

in parse server appId and masterKey are configured in the code where you initialize the ParseServer instance.

Go to you parse-server project 
open index.js and take the appId and masterKey from there..

```js
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var app = express();

var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev', // Connection string for your MongoDB database
  cloud: '/home/myApp/cloud/main.js', // Absolute path to your Cloud Code
  appId: 'myAppId',
  masterKey: 'myMasterKey', // Keep this key secret!
  fileKey: 'optionalFileKey',
  serverURL: 'http://localhost:1337/parse' // Don't forget to change to https if needed
});

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
app.use('/parse', api);

app.listen(1337, function() {
  console.log('parse-server-example running on port 1337.');
});
```

There you can see your appId and masterKey copy those values and paste them to your dashboard config.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In my case the file name was server.js. Where I found masterkey and appID to connect to parse server but, I am using PHP SDK to connect which also requires client key to connect. I tried to define it in this file but it didn't worked.

Comment: Did you also added the clientKey to your NodeJs parse-server?

Comment: Yes I added other keys already. Now its working fine Actually the problem was not on the server end it was on the security group previously I defined **allow all type of traffic on all ports from anywhere** along with 1 other rule allow **http traffic on port 80 from anywhere** . So I don't know they are overriding each other or what. But when I deleted **http** rule it just works fine.